# Floating divs in list (Google Chrome)

Tags: html, list, google-chrome

I need two divs to be next to eachother in a list. The following code works fine in Firefox, but not in Google Chrome:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div style="float:left;">DIV 1</div>
        <div>DIV 2</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

See the bullet position in Google Chrome:

[Bullet position in Google Chomre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI0Cp.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is not working? This fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/1odd1ju6/, works in both Chrome and Firefox (granted the placement of the list dot is different - is that the issue?).

Comment: Yes, the position of the bullet is different. In Google Chrome it's "between" the two divs. I uploaded an image in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `float:left;` use `display:inline-block;` on both div's. That will allow them to be in the same line. Here's an updated Fiddle showing that: https://jsfiddle.net/1odd1ju6/1/

Comment: Any idea how to use your solution to achieve the following behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/1odd1ju6/2/

(The content of the second div stays under the second div.)

Comment: @user2939345 you could look into using a table in that case? Or checkout some of the `display` `table-` properties here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class=container style="width:100%;">
<div class=left style="float:left; height: 200px; width: 200px; border-style:dotted;">
</div>
<div class=right style="float:right; height: 200px; width: 200px; border-style:dotted;">
</div>
</div>
```

now add padding and margin to left and right div as you want